# How to identlfy unused css selectors and rules for css pages which cover multiple pages and are installed locally?

Tags: css, web-development

I'm looking for a tool which would be able to identify unused and/or duplicate css selectors and rules, with the following two restrictions:

- The tool would have to be able to analyze css pages which are used for many HTML pages, so a tool like Dust-Me won't help.
- The tool should also work on a local installation, because I'd also like to be able to check my css at development stage. This would rule out online css verifiers.

Answer (score 5):

There is a Firefox addon called [CSS Usage](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/css-usage/) which shows all styles used/unused on a page.

It claims to do multiple pages but in my experience it seems to be somewhat unreliable in its results. Regardless it has helped me out a bunch in the past.

Answer (score 1):

I have tried Dust Me and CSS Usage in the past with some success to get an initial list of unused css selectors. Then what I do is focus on searching for those potentially unused selectors manually. At least that reduces the scope of the problem from hundreds of selectors to a few dozens.