# Tool or plugin required to show out in which html files a given css selectors is used

Tags: html, css, tools

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to identlfy unused css selectors and rules for css pages which cover multiple pages and are installed locally?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/16995/how-to-identlfy-unused-css-selectors-and-rules-for-css-pages-which-cover-multipl)

I'm looking for a tool which is capable of indicating in which html files a css selector is being used.

Ideally, this would also work on localhost.

Comment: Uh, you can't wait for answers? http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/16995/how-to-identlfy-unused-css-selectors-and-rules-for-css-pages-which-cover-multiple

Comment: @feeela sorry, but although both questions are related to css, you'll see they are not identical if you read carefully. This question is about used selectors and where they are used, the other one is about UNused selectors.

Comment: And if have know about all unused selectors in a CSS-file, you automatically know about all used selectors…

Comment: @feeela basically correct, however what I'm interested in is not only which ones are used, but where they are used, i.e. which html files contain a certain class or id, so that, when I modify it, I know which pages are impacted and will not forget any.

Comment: These questions are similar enough that they should just be combined.

Comment: Agreed. The other question can be edited to cover this question as well.

Answer (score 0):

If you code in an IDE that has a notion of projects then the easiest way is to to a project wide search for the selector of your choice.

If it needs to be in the final HTML that gets parsed, I don't know sorry.